# ant replaceregex replace multiline

Tags: ant

I need replace multiline string in file, like this:

```
startString
bla bla bla
...
endString
```

by ant replaceregex.
Ant code:

```
    <copy file="${file}" tofile="${newFile}" overwrite="true">
        <filterchain>
            <replaceregex pattern="startString(.+)endString" replace="zzz" flags="gmi" byline="true"/>
        </filterchain>      
    </copy>
```

If text for replace is Single line - all works correct, but when text is multiline - replaceregex  doesn't work.
What I should fix in my code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a couple of changes you need to do.  There are a couple of settings you had suggesting that each line of input should be considered a separate line of input which are the `byline` attribute and the `m` flag.  In the following I have removed those and also added the `s` flag which treats the input file a single line of input:

```
<replaceregex pattern="startString(.+?)endString" replace="zzz"
    flags="gis" byline="false"/>
```

Also note the addition of the `?` in the regex, this makes the wildcard non greedy in case you have multiple occurrences you want to match.

**See**

The ant [ReplaceRegExp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) documentation for more.